# CSS: Selecting a group of parents

Tags: html, css

For the following generated HTML:

```
<div id="parent1">
   <div class="child" />
</div>
<div id="parent2"> 
    <div class="child" />
</div>
<div id="parent3"> 
    <div class="child" />
</div>
```

I would like to select .child from #parent1 and #parent2 like:

```
#parent1 .child, #parent2 .child { Do stuff... }
```

However, this can become messy. Is it possible to select a group of parents like this?

```
(#parent1, #parent2) .child { Do stuff... }
```

Comment: With just HTML and CSS, no. You would need to use a dynamic style sheet language like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: It seems like the solution you're looking for would actually be much more complicated than your current method or adding a class to each element that you would like to change

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree. However due to content generation this is not a option.

Comment: Maybe you should include more code in your question so you don't get stuck with the [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors L4 draft introduces [`:matches()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#matches). It allows you to do

```css
:matches(#parent1, #parent2) .child
```

Note it's an experimental feature, and browsers haven't implemented it yet. However, some support `:-moz-any` or `:-webkit-any`, which behave like `:matches`.

```css
:-moz-any(#parent1, #parent2) .child {
  color: blue;
}
:-webkit-any(#parent1, #parent2) .child {
  color: blue;
}
:matches(#parent1, #parent2) .child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent1">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div id="parent2"> 
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div id="parent3"> 
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the `[attribute^=value]` ([begin with](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)) or `[attribute*=value]` ([contain](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)) syntax.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
<div id="parent2"> 
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
<div id="anotherParent"> 
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[id^=parent] .child {
    color: red;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/eh5saf1k/

But I think it's better to asign the same `class` simply.

Comment: Interesting syntax. However this selects all parents with that pattern, which can be problematic. I've updated the HTML in my post.

Comment: Why not you simply assign the same `class` to desired elements?

Comment: Because of content generation by Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [nesting](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3), and you'll need to use SASS or SCSS for that: http://jsfiddle.net/soy3tdmy/

```
#parent1, #parent2 {
    .child {
        color: red;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```